# ChartJS + jQuery = Chart not showing

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I'm trying to create a Dounught chart with ChartJS:

```
$(function() {
    //...

    drawChart();
});

function drawChart() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("currenciesTag").getContext("2d");

    new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ['Label1', 'Label2'],
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: ['#000000', '#000000'],
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: [1, 2],
            }]
        },
        options: {}
    });
}
```

Actually, I need to draw my chart in $(function() {} because dataset comes from elements used by jQuery.
But, my chart is not showing. Its canvas is resized so something happens.

If I put the content of drawChart() outside any function, it works and my charts is showing. But I need to draw it from inside $(function() {}

UPDATE 1
console.log(ctx):
[image: console.log(ctx);]

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not able to get a hold of `ctx`.

Inspect with the console like this:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("currenciesTag").getContext("2d");
console.log(ctx);
```

Check your html and make sure you have, for example:

```
<body>
  <canvas id="currenciesTag" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

You can see your code working here:

https://jsfiddle.net/zwjj20L5/

Comment: I did exactly the same thing and it does not work if I draw the chart from the method.

Comment: I added console.log(ctx) result in my opriginal post

Comment: Then something happens before `drawChart();`, it does not get called.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and it takes 4.5 hours to solve it god damn nevermind if you have

```
window.onload = function() { }
```

outside of your

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
```

code just delete it after that you can use it in any function like $(function() { }); or button click. Have a nice day :)